# How to markup a ladder/draw

Tags: html, css, semantics

I need to markup a ladder for upcoming tournaments, and I can't find any way to mark it up semantically. The only way I've seen so far is to [mark it up as a table](http://ngri.ozfortress.com/), and I'd like to avoid that at all costs.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why avoid using a table? It is tabular data. Semantically, a table would be the best choice.

Comment: Just coz it looks basically like a table it doesn't mean it's tabular data. The horizontal relationships are a bit trickier than just table rows, and I think a list of matches is a more accurate way to think of the matches than as a column of data in a table. Though maybe a combination of tables and lists woudl be best

Answer (score 1):

I've found one example at [Accessible NCAA Tournament Bracket](http://staff.washington.edu/tft/ncaa/bracket2008.html) which uses a mix of `ul`/`li` to achieve it. It's far from perfect (it could uses `li + li` instead of the "top/bottom" classes, but it's a start.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by '`li + li` instead of the "top/bottom" classes'? The list does use `li` tags for that. Great example though, thanks!

Comment: I meant you could have css rules for `li` with `li` sibling to separate the first li from the second, instead of having to mark them `<li class='top'>` as they do on the example.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this, although would also maybe add title attributes to the list items also in order to make the horizontal relationship more accessible

```
eg <li class="gameThree" title="winner of round One game 2 vs winner of round one game 5">

<ol id="tournamentLadder">
<li id="roundOne">
<ul class="matches">
    <li class="gameOne>
        <ol class="teams">
            <li class="home">Teamname1</li>
            <li class="visitors">Teamname2</li>  
        </ol> 
    </li>
</ul>

</li>
<li id="roundTwo">

</li>


<li id=final">
</li>

</ol>
```

Comment: I disagree with using a `ul` for `.matches`, as it should be ordered. Thanks though!